# Multiple SKU to share one inventory?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, inventory, sku, bundle

The scenario is as follows:

I sell unisex clothes. As a result I used a Gender attribute on the product page to allow the customer the option of seeing a male model wearing the item and a female model wearing the exact same item - the main image is interchangeable depending on switching the product attribute gender otherwise product is exactly the same. Ultimately, I am using an attribute for the sake of changing the image but not the product itself.

*Other attributes include Size and Quantity only.*

As is well known an SKU cannot be duplicated. My question is: Considering the above, what options are available to ensure alternative SKU's share the same inventory?

Or is there an alternative? Such as Bundles, that still allow the alternating main image on gender option change?

Thank you in advance,
A